# Camel SFTP file processing issue

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am trying to fetch file from SFTP server using camel ftp component and process it in a custom way.I am able to successfully connect to sftp server and fetch the file but the exchange body contains remote file object and the file contains com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry object,when i inspected the file object in debug mode it contained only metadata information about  the file. I am getting type cast exception while casting it to a file.How do i get the file from exchange object for further custom processing.

When i use file instead of SFTP everything works fine.

Camel Route:

```
<camelContext id="SourceContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeContextRef ref="SourceTranslatorRouteContext" />
        <threadPoolProfile customId="true"
            id="SourceSplitThreadProfile" maxPoolSize="100" maxQueueSize="0"
            poolSize="20" />
        <route id="SourceOutWriteConsumerRoute" streamCache="true">
            <from id="SourceEndpoint"
                uri="sftp:{{SourceFtpHostname}}:22/{{directoryName}}?siteCommand=NAMEFMT 
                1&amp;stepwise=false&amp;fileName={{fileName}}&amp;password={{SourceFtpPWD}}&amp;username={{SourceFtpUname}}&amp;useList=false&amp;delete=true" />
            <!-- <from id="SourceEndpoint" uri="file:{{directoryName}}?fileName={{fileName}}"/> -->

            <removeHeaders id="_removeHeaders1" pattern="Camel*" />
            <doTry id="_doTry1">

                <setProperty id="_setProperty1" propertyName="policySublobGroup">
                    <simple>{{policySublobGroup}}</simple>
                </setProperty>
                <split id="_split1" parallelProcessing="true" streaming="true">
                    <method bean="customSplitter" method="splitPolicy" />

                </split>

                <doCatch id="_doCatch1">
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                    <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                    </handled>
                    <
                </doCatch>

            </doTry>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Java method for custom processing of csv.

```
public static List<List<Policy>> splitPolicy(final Exchange exchange) {
        // String line = "";

        GenericFile file = exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class);
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        List<List<Policy>> splitList = new ArrayList<List<Policy>>();
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream((File) file.getFile());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            br.readLine();
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {

                String[] Details = line.split(";");
                //logic to add splitList
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("IOException  occured in splitPolicy", e);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured in splitPolicy", e);

        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error occured in while closing resource in method splitPolicy ", e);
            }
        }

        return splitList;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
04:00:03,236 ERROR  (Camel (SOURCESYSTEMContext) thread #43 - sftp://SOURCESYSTEM.company.parentcompany:22/home/company/SOURCESYSTEM/TEST/OUT/MOAPP) Exception occured in splitPolicy: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry cannot be cast to java.io.File
    at com.company.esb.SOURCESYSTEM.CustomSplitter.splitPolicy(CustomSplitter.java:51) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:177) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:68) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$InvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:211) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:126) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:138) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairs(Splitter.java:113) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:231) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:108) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:63) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:171) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137) [camel-ftp-2.17.0.redhat-630262.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630262]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:226) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:190) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630283.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630283]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: What happens if you change to `File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);`? That works for me when fetching from SFTP at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ask Camel to get the message body as an input stream, or String etc

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
```